# How can I link to a .php page from my html page

Tags: php, html

I hope I didn't make my question too vague but what I need is being able to redirect from an index.html page to an login.php page, is that a possibility?

I am using xampp and hosting it locally (the site im making wont go online, just practicing)

Here's the code that I use:

```
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="bloemen.html">onze bloemen bekijken></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="inloggen.php">Login</a></li>       
    </ul>
```

Oh and sorry if this has been posted before, I haven't found any threads like this and couldn't find anything on Google.

Kind regards,

Tom

Comment: there are too many ways to do this.

Comment: Great to hear that! would you mind letting me know an easy way to do this? I have been struggling on this issue for a fair bit.

Comment: Struggling in what way?

Comment: whats wrong with what you are doing? Using a link is the way to go. someone click the link and then they goto that page.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. `<a href="inloggen.php">` should do it, what happens when you click that? Does your server have PHP running?

Comment: When I click on the href I go directly to the script as seen here: http://i.imgur.com/lnlyoUy.png and I do have PHP running

Comment: The source is displayed like that or that is the pages code?

Comment: if it is not displaying code  and not content  then PHP is not running on the computer

Comment: @user3005775 or the webserver is not configured to run PHP.

Comment: @siet, supposedly it is running localhost, so that is why I said computer

Comment: What is was trying to say is that PHP could be installed only the webserver configuration does not have the correct settings, like path to PHP binary etc

Comment: ... or the `.html` file is just being opened in the browser rather than through `http` - so the `.php` page is also being opened through `file:///`

Comment: Oh nevermind I found out what the issue was.. wow that is even stupid for my doing.. I used file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.html instead of going via localhost/index.html.. Thanks everyone for the quick replies!

Comment: ^ taaadaaaaa! (Occam's Razor) ;)

Comment: The question was closed as per: *"Oh nevermind I found out what the issue was.. wow that is even stupid for my doing.. I used file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/index.html instead of going via localhost/index.html"*.